# Prevent duplicate values in mysql nested tables using sequelize

Tags: mysql, json, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I am unable to find out duplicate rows exist or not. I have 3 tables with following table structure.

```
domaintable

--------------------
|  id     name     |
--------------------
|  1      car      |
|  2      student  | 
|__________________|

domaintableschema

-------------------------------------------
| id  domaintableId columnName   type     |
-------------------------------------------
|  1      1          model       string   |
|  2      1          year        string   |
|  3      2          name        string   |
|  4      2          gender      string   |
-------------------------------------------


domaintabledata

----------------------------------------------
| id   domaintableschemaId    row     value   |
----------------------------------------------
| 1       1                    1       Jaguar |
| 2       2                    1       2016   |
| 3       3                    1       Joe    |
| 4       4                    1       male   |
| 5       3                    2       Jake   |
| 6       4                    2       female |
|_____________________________________________|
```

In the user interface, the tables car and students are shown as domain tables. User have privilege to create more domain tables with any domain schema. But user is not allowed to insert duplicate values into domain table data. The API payload to insert data as follows, suppose user wants to insert into student table with values `male` and `Jake`.

```
{
 "0": {
   "domaintableschemaId": 4,
   "value": "male",
   "row": 3
  },
  "1": {
    "domaintableschemaId": 3,
    "value": "Joe",
    "row": 3
  }
}
```

what I have tried, I wrote following query to avoid duplicates but it doesn't work in all the cases. The approach, I formed `schemaId = [4, 3]` and `value = [ "Joe", "male"]`

`SELECT * from domaintabledata where values in $value and schemaId in $schemaId` which returns rows array, any array element with the length equal to payload will decide duplicate present or not. But it will not work when I have to insert following row (note: values are same, only schema ids are revered)

```
{
 "0": {
   "domaintableschemaId": 3,
   "value": "male",
   "row": 3
  },
  "1": {
    "domaintableschemaId": 4,
    "value": "Joe",
    "row": 3
  }
}
```

Even though the above value is not duplicate, my solution will not allow to insert as the values are same and out of rows returned one row length will be same as row to be inserted. Please help me with any elegant approach to prevent inserting duplicate values. I use sequelize and sequelize-hierarchy as ORM.

Comment: create an index and specify unique: true

Comment: we can add primary key to avoid duplication in rows.